# Server sent event sends data repeatedly

Tags: php, javascript, server-sent-events

I'm a student and i'm doing a project for a social trading platform. I would like to implement a notification system and i think SSE is a good idea. However, my SSE code sends data repeatedly for some reason (i only want to send once). Im running these scripts on XAMMP APACHE in localhost.

SSE sse.php

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
function sendMsg($id, $msg) {
  echo "id: $id" . PHP_EOL;
  echo "data: $msg" . PHP_EOL;
  echo PHP_EOL;
  ob_flush();
  flush();
}
$serverTime = time();
sendMsg($serverTime, 'server time: ' . date("h:i:s", time()));
?>
```

Client financials.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h1>Getting server updates</h1>
<div id="result"></div>

<script>
if(typeof(EventSource)!=="undefined")
  {
  var source=new EventSource("sse.php");
  source.onmessage=function(event)
    {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML+=event.data + "<br>";
    };
  }
else
  {
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="Sorry, your browser does not support server-sent events...";
  }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance for any help rendered :).

Comment: hover your mouse over the `server-sent-events` tag.

Comment: It seems that the server is simply sending a single message, then closing the connection like a normal, non-SSE request. The client then reconnects, like it's supposed to when the server closes an SSE connection. So this appears to you like the server is sending information repeatedly, because it is. Generally an SSE server is one which doesn't close the connection. It waits until data is available to it, then it sends the information, via your sendMsg() function, in a loop. Try placing your calls to sendMsg() in a loop with a sleep(3) in each iteration. This should be a good start for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSE is designed to send messages repeatedly (say, the connection will always be open unless you call `close` method).

> Server-Sent Events (SSE) are a a part of the HTML5 specification. SSE allows a uni-directional persistent connection between a client and server, such that the client makes only a single request and the server keeps pushing data to the client continuously, until the connection is closed.

The frequency can be set through the `retry` field. For detailed information, you can check it out [HERE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events).

In a previous project of mine, I made use of the `id` field to uniquely identify an event. When the client received the event, check whether the event had been handled. If not, handle it. Otherwise, ignore it. You can set the fields by:

```
echo "retry: xx"
echo "id: xx"
```

However, since you want to make a trading system, I do not think SSE is a good idea. From my perspective, SSE is good for massively spread messages instead of send message to a specific client. I recommend web socket.

BTW: never forget the trailing '\n'...

Comment: `PHP_EOL` is a combination of `\r\n` depending on the OS.